# Importing feedback from MS Access to show in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-access

After inserting/updating on Query design in MS Access, we get feedback like "5 rows have been updated/Inserted". How can we import this feedback and show it in VB.net in a Textbox/MessageBox Or If we can do it?

Comment: How are you accessing the database from the application?  Often times data access methods which execute non-select queries (insert/update/delete) will return or otherwise make available the number of rows affected.

Comment: Using Connection String, with ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: *"ExecuteReader() using a while loop"* - That doesn't sound like an insert/update query.  `ExecuteReader` is for *selecting* data, and that `while` loop is where you read the data you selected.  If you're looking for the number of rows returned then you can get that from the number of iterations of the loop.

Comment: You are right. It was ExecuteNonQuery(), sorry. Yeah, that's a good idea. But still, I wonder is there any possibility to get the feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments above, you are using `ExecuteNonQuery()` to invoke your SQL commands.  According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery) (or [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery)?), the return value of that method is the number of rows affected.  For example:

```
var rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
// do whatever you like with rowsAffected, display to the user, etc.
```

or:

```
Dim rowsAffected As Int32 = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
' do whatever you like with rowsAffected, display to the user, etc.
```